# Dropdown list appearing different on firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

[Chrome and Firefox Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k0N2.jpg)

Website URL : http://54.169.116.127/amsyt/index.php

As we can see in the screenshot. Menu Bar is appearing behind the texts on the header in Firefox. Is there any way to make it above the text, like in the chrome browser ? Z-index is not working.
Website link is provided for experimental purposes.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sir, I provided the link of my webpage we can easily inspect the coding like other people did. I have my solution now. Thank you for your concern

Comment: it's not our job to inspect your webpage. Next time you ask something give `MCV` so its easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove z-index from style.css from class carousel-caption and lampontop

Answer (score 0):

Add the css rules below in your css file

```
.lampontop{z-index:1}
.carousel-caption{z-index:1}
.dropdown-menu{z-index:27}
```